# How can i create a notification if my MainActivity is destroyed in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My app is based in periodically background works, it works fine during my app is active, but when running during some hours the system kills my MainActivity even if it has permission for not optimize the battery. But the services in background continuing working. My problem is when these services need to show a notification appears an exception because i can't launch the activity "You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); pior to using this property.".

And also can't start foreground services because they depend on notifications too

How can i solve it?

here is when create the notifications

```
public void Show(string title, string message, int Id, string Type)
{
try
{
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
intent.PutExtra(MsgIdKey, Id.ToString());
intent.PutExtra(MsgTypeKey, Type);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetContentTitle(title)
    .SetContentText(message)
    .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Logo2_6_10x10))
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Logo2_6_10x10)
    .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(message));
Notification notification = builder.Build();

notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);
}
catch
{}
}
```

i tried to show notifications without MainActivity but appears a NullReference exception in

`manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationReciever));
//Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction("com.DCVSYS.Adminsentinel.TEST");
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
intent.PutExtra(MsgIdKey, Id.ToString());
intent.PutExtra(MsgTypeKey, Type);
context.SendBroadcast(intent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33)
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
else
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
```

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.DCVSYS.Adminsentinel.NotificationReciever", Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.DCVSYS.Adminsentinel.TEST" })]
public class NotificationReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string channelId = "default";
    const int pendingIntentId = 0;

    int messageId = 0;
    NotificationManager manager;
    private static Context context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        string title = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.TitleKey);
        string message = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.MessageKey);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Logo2_6_10x10))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Logo2_6_10x10)
                //.SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
                .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(message));
        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

        manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); pior to using this property

You can recheck if you have used method `OnCreate()` method correctly and added `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` to your activity.

Please refer to the following code:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
       
    }
```

Comment: yes @JessieZhang, i have it, but my activity is closed by the system and when i want to create a notification the Intent not launch MainActivity again, and then it miss this initialization, i believe...

Comment: Have you tried restarting your app?

Comment: are there any method for restarting a app? in onDestroy()  doesn't work the intent either.

Comment: You can try to use service to achieve this. For information, please check : [Building an Android service that never stops running](https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/).

Comment: The current Android is a good shit!, i was create a foreground service only because my app did needs using the vibrate phone (when the app is in background vibrate not works). but i can't using a foreground service when the MainActivity is killed because need to create a notification for the foreground service. it is the same problem that before.

Comment: Could you please share [a basic demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here so that we can test on our side?

Comment: My app is based with `AlarmManager` for polling an server periodically. I will try to implement a foreground service for do this task like you say in previous message. maybe if this service running, android will not kill the MainActivity. I will say if works or not. In this way I will also solve the polling server period issue. Because `CanScheduleExactAlarms()`  doesn't work too.

Comment: Waiting for your good news. :)

Comment: i'm sorry i have been very busy until now and i have been can not implement the foreground in my code. Well the androind can't kill the `MainActivity` now but the frequency to polling into the server is constant (each 30 seconds) in idle mode arround the 8 or 10 times and then begins to stuck, osciling to arround 5- 7- 10-20 min sometimes 30 seconds again. i try different kinds of delays but not solve it. if i take off the wake lock is worse, if i take off the part of connection to server (running the loop only) have the same behavior. i think it is impossible.